# Yield in Python performances comparison

Tags: python

i'm reading about the Yield expression and generators in Python, this approach it's really encouraged during huge calculations.

To check that, i've created a simple .py script, in order to measure the time between one approach, using the yield expression and in memory range built-in class.

Here is the script:

```
import time

def pow():
    for i in  range(100000000):
        yield i*i


start_time = time.time()

for i in pow():
    res = i

print('Seconds Yield: {0}'.format(time.time() - start_time))

start_time = time.time()

for i in range(100000000):
    res = i*i

print('Seconds in-memory: {0}'.format(time.time() - start_time))
```

it's a little bit strange behavior, because, i've run the script via my terminal and the results are:

```
Seconds Yield: 17.303140878677368
Seconds in-memory: 17.322022914886475
```

I was expecting a lower value on the "yield" approach, but in any case is higher than the "in memory approach".

I've checked on my system monitor if there was differences in therm of used RAM or CPU, but are the same in any case...

...Can someone is able to explain me why???

Thanks.

Comment: If you're on Python 2.x, using `xrange` instead of `range` may help demonstrate the concept better

Comment: Why do you expect there to be a difference?  In both cases, you're looping over 100000000 elements and squaring each -- So the amount of work in both cases will be roughly the same.  Intermediate storage will be the same too (you call the same functions, in both cases).

Comment: I'm on python 3.5.1

Comment: yield is not typically done for speed reasons ... it is usually a memory conserving thing

Comment: Using `yield` is not multi-threading!

Comment: The code you call "in-memory" isn't actually putting more things in memory at once than the other code.

Comment: range is also a generator, so under the hood it is grabbing one result at a time.  The slight difference in time might be caused by the overhead of calling `pow()`

Comment: @MosesKoledoye He didn't tag python 3 but the prints are functions, so its a good guess.

Comment: @joelgoldstick Didn't notice notice that.Good eye ;)

Comment: And so? when i have to use or nor the Generators?